# Find rows in dataframe with dict

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
```

produces

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Given a dict

```
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 5}
```

how would I extract the rows of the dataframe where the dict's keys values match all the column values -- so in this case

```
   a  b
1  2  5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare with `Series` and filter:

```
df[(df == pd.Series(d)).all(1)]

   a  b
1  2  5
```

This comparison is aligned on the index/columns and broadcasted for each row.

Comment: This answer helped me in here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593478/find-a-series-in-dataframe-and-update-it

Comment: I said it helped me. It did not completely solved the problem. The tricky point is how to update backed hackedrow. Can you help in there?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the values and use indexing,

```
df[ (df.values == np.array(list(d.values()))).all(1) ]

    a   b
1   2   5
```