# Find a series in dataframe and replace it with original row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have below dataframe `df` but some `D4`s with `True` was causing an issue in [my custom ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555995/multiple-conditions-on-pandas-dataframe). Temporarily, I stored such rows in a list and turned those `D4` values to `False` intentionally and sorted with my custom ordering.

```
Index D1  D2  D3   D4      D5
    0   8   5   0  False   True
    1  45  35   0   True  False
    2  35  10   1  False   True
    3  40   5   0   True  False
    4  12  10   5  False  False
    5  18  15  13  False   True
    6  25  15   5   True  False
    7  35  10  11  False   True
    8  95  50   0  False  False

hacked_rows = []
def hack_d4(row):
    if row['D3'] in [0, 1]:
       row['D4'] = False
       hacked_rows.append(row)
    return row
df_hacked = df.apply(lambda x: hack_d4(x), axis=1)
ordered_df = order_df(df_hacked) # Returns same df with some rows in custom order.
```

So, Technically, in short I have to revert below  `ordered_df` to the original `df` with the help of list `hacked_rows`.  Row Order is not important, only hacked rows should be replaced back in the original dataset.

```
    Index   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
0   0   8   5   0   False   True
2   2   35  10  1   False   True
3   3   40  5   0   False   False
1   1   45  35  0   False   False
5   5   18  15  13  False   True
4   4   12  10  5   False   False
7   7   35  10  11  False   True
8   8   95  50  0   False   False
6   6   25  15  5   True    False
```

Now I am done with [custom ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555995/multiple-conditions-on-pandas-dataframe). Now I want to revert `hacked_rows` back to the original dataframe which are there on the list, but not sure how to replace them back.

I tried below code for one row, but no luck, its throwing `TypeError`:

```
item = hacked_rows[0]
item = item.drop('D3')
ordered_df.loc[item]    # But this line is throwing error.
```

*Note*- I am okay if anyone can suggest a different approach to replace the `True` values temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is when you create the data frame again.

```
hacked_rows = []
def hack_d4(row):
    if row['D3'] in [0, 1]:
        row['D4'] = False
        hacked_rows.append(row)
    return row
df = df.apply(lambda x: hack_d4(x), axis=1)
ordered_df = pd.DataFrame(df) # code update

df
    Index   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
0   0   8   5   0   False   True
1   1   45  35  0   False   False
2   2   35  10  1   False   True
3   3   40  5   0   False   False
4   4   12  10  5   False   False
5   5   18  15  13  False   True
6   6   25  15  5   True    False
7   7   35  10  11  False   True
8   8   95  50  0   False   False
```

**Update:**
I added the code with the understanding that I wanted to convert the `hacked_rows` to a list of data frames, with the comment you gave me.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=[])
for i in hacked_rows:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, pd.Series(i)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
new_df.stack().unstack(level=1).T


Index   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
1   0   8   5   0   False   True
2   1   45  35  0   False   False
3   2   35  10  1   False   True
4   3   40  5   0   False   False
5   8   95  50  0   False   False
```

Comment: No, error is there in the line - `ordered_df.loc[item]` , Not really when I am doing the custom ordering

Comment: I understood the question to be about not being able to undo the `hacked_rows`. Could you please add the expected output to the question?

Comment: Yes, edited now. Please check. In short, I have to revert `hacked_rows` in the `ordered_df`

Comment: @r-beginners- not really, In your code replace `new_df` with `ordered_df`. But still `pd.concat` won't help as the  `i` in `hacked_rows` should get replaced with the original row only. It should not change the order of the dataframe rows.